# Generalization of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory

Let $X$ be a set. Write $S(X)$ for the set of all bijections $X\longrightarrow X$. One can easily see that $S(X\sqcup\{\operatorname{pt}\})\cong (X\sqcup\{\operatorname{pt}\})\times S(X)$, where $\sqcup$ denotes the disjoint union of sets. Propably, you have seen such an argument when computing the order of finite symmetric groups. We could call the cardinality of $S(X)$ the **generalized factorial** and denote it by $X!$.

For two sets $X,Y$ write $B(X,Y)=\left\{A\in\mathfrak{P}(X)\;\middle|\;A\text{ is equipotent to }Y\right\}$ for the **generalized binomial coefficient**.

Is it true, that $$S(X)\cong S(Y)\times S(X-Y)\times B(X,Y)$$
whenever $Y$ injects into $X$? How can I see this? If not, is there some other useful generalisation of the binomial coefficient to sets of arbitrary sizes?

Comment: What does $\sqcup$ mean here? Disjoint union?

Comment: @HenningMakholm $X\sqcup Y$=disjoint union/sum of sets

Comment: For infinite sets cardinal arithmetic is pretty boring. The answer is fairly trivially yes. Unless you don't talk about cardinal arithmetic in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

Let $Y\subseteq X$ be fixed, and choose for every $Z\in B(X,Y)$ a bijection $g_Z: Z\to Y$, and for every $W \in B(X,X\setminus Y)$ a bijection $h_W: W\to X\setminus Y$.

Then given $(\varphi,\psi,A)\in S(Y)\times S(X\setminus Y)\times B(X,Y)$, let
$$ f_{(\varphi,\psi,A)}(x) = \begin{cases}
\varphi(g_A(x)) & \text{if }x\in A \\
\psi(h_{X\setminus A}(x)) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

$f$ is then a bijection $S(Y)\times S(X\setminus Y)\times B(X,Y)\to S(X)$. For a general element of $S(X)$, $A$ encodes those elements that map into $Y$, and $\phi$ encodes *how* they map into $Y$ given the choice of $g$s.

Comment: I suppose in the same manner, it can be shown that $B(X,Y)\sqcup B(X,Y\sqcup 1)\cong B(X\sqcup 1,Y\sqcup 1)$. I will try to do this on my own.